# ReferenceError: "getLastPopulatedRow" is not defined

Tags: google-sheets

Good night,

I'm creating a spreadsheet on google with the goal of automating the storage and management of data. To do this, people fill in the data in an "Entries" tab and I need to develop a script that launches this data into the "DB" database.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U9ib.png)

In this image it shows the flap people fill in. My idea is that with a button at the end of the fill the information will be sent to the database as shown below:

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTAQL.png)

I put the colors referring to the columns that should be copied in "Entries" and pasted in "BD"

I tried to create the following script:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('Entradas!B9:J29');
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BD');
  var lastFilledRowInColumnA = getLastPopulatedRow(destSheet.getRange('A:A').getValues());
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnA+1,1);
  source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear();
};
```

But, I can not do the copying and pasting of information.

Can you help me please. I've been trying for over two months and I can not seem to sort it out.

Follow the link to the spreadsheet template:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BuLBU2qKB8ZNMi_wVvTHwW6MyODDTKPoP5Imn1r1L7Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such prepared method in Google Apps Script. In your script, a function of ``getLastPopulatedRow()`` is required to be put in your project. If you are using a script copied from other site, how about checking it again? By the way, about ``lastFilledRowInColumnB``, from the variable name, if you want to retrieve the last row of column "B", I think that the values of "B:K" include the unnecessary values. Can I ask you about the value you want here?

Comment: Good Morning!

I need to copy as a row from one flap and paste on the other flap with an empty line

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. From ``I need to copy as a row from one flap and paste on the other flap with an empty line``, I cannot understand the concrete vision you want. So can you provide the detail information of input and output you want? And also can you provide a sample spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information. By the way, can I ask you about the function of ``getLastPopulatedRow()``?

Comment: Hello, good morning.
I am sending the sheet so you can see more clearly what I need. 
The input data goes into the "Input" tab, then I need the information that I put in there going into the "Data" tab, in the respective colunm. 
For instance, the colunm "Cliente" in the input tab needs to go to the colunm "Cleinte" in the "Data" tab. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bhVVCeJfgy31U3-rVVQqZ6PDez7AlXSICueXaWUJ2YY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanksfor your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot see the shared spreadsheet. Also I think that when I can see the sample spreadsheet, it will help to understand your situation. So could you please confirm it?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WM-kqRoRDDNppBvAKUKFHmYmMSNCZmQdMaLVJWWkaVY

Comment: Please, try to use this link.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could see the sample spreadsheet. But unfortunately, I cannot find "Input" and "Data" tabs in your comment, and also I cannot see your latest script. So I cannot understand about what you want to do. Can you update your question by including the detail information and flow you want to do? It will help users think of your solution.

Comment: @AdrianaCruz Welcome. Would you please edit your question to include an example of the source layout and the expected destination layout. The columns in sheet "Entradas" are very different to the ones in sheet "BD". In addition, you appear to be copying 20 rows (B9:J29) but your target is just one cell. Your explanation does not cover these things.

Comment: Okay, I tried to explain the question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP original code was being brought undone by the `getlastrow` command. I've replaced this with looking at specific columns of data  (Entradas-Column B, and BD-Column A) and using the length command to get an accurate row count. I've also left a series of Logger commands in the code so that OP can check key values if/when the need arises.

I used the `copyValuesToRange` ([*documentation*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangesheet-column-columnend-row-rowend)) command  to copy the data, and the `clear` command (as used by the OP, but with the `contentsOnly` ([*documentation*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearoptions)) option.

Lastly, the OP should format Sheet-BD, Column A as date, and also remove any data validation from BD.

```
function movedata() {

  // setup basics for spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // source and destination sheets
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Entradas");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BD');

  // calculate the last row on the source
  var Sourcevals = sourceSheet.getRange("B9:B").getValues();
  var Sourcelast = Sourcevals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: last row in Source = " + Sourcelast);//DEBUG

  //if there is no data to copy, then stop the code.
  if (Sourcelast ==0){
    Logger.log(" there is no data - stop the code");
    return;
  }

  // define the Source Range and get the Source data  
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(9, 2, Sourcelast, 9);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: source range: " + sourceRange.getA1Notation());// DEBUG
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();

  // calculate the last row on the destination
  var Destvals = destSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Destlast = Destvals.filter(String).length;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: last row in column A = " + Destlast);// DEBUG

  // copy the data fro Source to destination
  sourceRange.copyValuesToRange(destSheet, 1, 11, Destlast + 1, Destlast + 1 + Sourcelast);
  // delete the data from the Source
  sourceRange.clear({contentsOnly: true});

}
```